# Get the source image file from img tag

Tags: javascript, html, caching, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I have an `img` tag with `src="www.example.com/pic1.jpeg"`.
The image file has already loaded fully.
Now I want to save the image file.

I can download it by using the link in the src attribute. But I want to save the image without internet.

I opened DevTools and I was able to locate the image file in the Sources Tab -> Network pane.
But still, I cannot able to save it without internet.

I use Chrome Canary Browser and Mac OS.

Comment: right click => Save Image As...

Comment: _"I was able to locate the image file in the Sources Tab -> Network pane. But still, I cannot able to save it without internet."_ Was the image at `Network` tab while you were offline?

Comment: @Kalaiselvan you stated that the image is "*already loaded fully*", at this point, you don't need any internet connection anymore to *Save Image As...*, except if you are in a really weird situation that would need clarifications on your part, since even in incognito mode I can do it.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks. It works.

Comment: @Kalaiselvan good to read it, you might want to delete your question, since it is borderline from being *off-topic, not about programming*, but rather destined to some sister site like https://superuser.com, and from being off-topic for *won't help future readers*, since it's unlikely someone else would come here with such a problem. But if you disagree, feel free to self-answer.

Comment: It's on-topic. There's a concrete path towards accomplishing this task in Chrome DevTools.

Answer (score 2):

When you click it on the network tab you will see a preview, right click it then save ...

edit :

i tried this and it worked : `ctrl + s` to save the page , it will be saved as html and another folder with the same name contains all content of that page including the pictures .

Comment: It won't work. Sure, we can do like that to save the image but active internet connection is required for that. That method is no different then copying the link from src attribute and use it to download the image.

Comment: i tried this and it worked : `ctrl + s` to save the page , it will be saved as html and another folder with the same name contains all content of that page including the pictures .

Answer (score 2):

Try  this in console

```
var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
try{
    url = "www.example.com/pic1.jpeg";
    linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
    linkElement.setAttribute("download", ');
    var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
        "view": window,
        "bubbles": true,
        "cancelable": false
    });
    linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);          
}
catch (ex){  
    console.log(ex)
}
```